# Loop differences

Tags: java

In Java is there a difference in the two loops in the timing:

```
for (int i=1; i<11; ++i)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

AND

```
for (int i=100; i<111; ++i)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: It will save some energy by setting off the bits ;)

Comment: @Jigar Joshi,  Off and on bit are likely to drain the same amount of energy. It changing the bits which uses energy the most energy. ;)

Comment: @Suresh :i think i am not very familiar with micro optimization... could you please elaborate? And please ignore the difference of 1 in the two loops... my bad... i meant : for int i=101; i<111; ++i) .... basically both loops running the same number of times but with different initialization values. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The second loop will run 1 more time than the first.

Comment: Also, values of `i` will be different ;-)

Comment: @Victor: true but the OP is talking about timings :)

Comment: the difference in the second instance would be equivalent to 0 to 11 in the first.

Answer (score 0):

Second loop will be executed one more time than the first one, since 111-100=11 and 11-1=10.

If you use

```
for (int i=101; i<111; ++i)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

then the result should be the same as the first loop, timing wise. Of course, things will be different if you actually use `i` in

```
// do stuff
```

part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one (micro)difference in the bytecode:

`i = 1`  will be translated to `ICONST_1`, while
`i = 100` results in `BIPUSH 100`

The first is a single opcode, while the second is an opcode followed by an byte which must be loaded and sign-extended to 32 bits. The first is typically more efficient than the second but I think the difference will be insignificant compared to the whole loop (`// do stuf`).

The second (`for (int i=100; i<111; ++i)`) surely should be preferred instead of:

```
for (int i=1; i<11; ++i)
{
  // do stuff with  (i + 100)
}
```

it's not only slower - adding 100 each interaction - but also less readable IMHO ...